# Using Comparing number and string in android

Tags: android

Hi to all android developer,

Can you help me about using comparing wildcard character in android.

*Example:*
**Numbers**

```
if( 6.7890666 = 6.789* ){
     "Match"
}else{
     "Not Macth"
}
```

**string**

```
if( "compare" = "com????" ){
     "Match"
}else{
     "Not Macth"
}
```

Can you help how code this in android program

Comment: You can use regular expressions. Look this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958147/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-wildcard-character-in-java).

Comment: So you want the first n character match?

Answer (score 0):

For comparing strings you must use equals.

e.g.

```
String a = "abcd";
if(a.equals("com"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a number do it like this,

```
 if(123 == 123)
```

if it is a string do it like this,

```
 if(abc.equals(abc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
String a = "compare";
if( a.equalsIgnoreCase("com???"))
{
     "Match"
}else
{
     "Not Macth"
}
```

equalsIgnoreCase function is not case sencitive.